# Restlet: getting parameter keys and values of a request

Tags: java, json, restlet

I have a Restlet Service that looks like this:

```
@POST
@Produces("application/json")
public String processImmediately(String JSON) {

    //...
}
```

The intention is to pass a JSON string via POST. The parameter I used (String JSON) indeed contains the whole URL parameters, e.g.

```
JSON=%7B%22MessageType%22%3A%22egeg%22%7D&SomeValue=XY
```

I wonder how I could parse this. On the Restlet website, I found the following:

http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.0/13-restlet/27-restlet/330-restlet/58-restlet.html

```
Form form = request.getResourceRef().getQueryAsForm();
for (Parameter parameter : form) {
System.out.print("parameter " + parameter.getName());
System.out.println("/" + parameter.getValue());
```

How can I use this in my service method? I am even not able to determine the correct types (e.g. request, form).
Do I need the method parameter any longer or is this a replacement?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your endpoint is being passed the entire query string because you didn't specify which part of it you want to consume. To bind just the `JSON` query parameter to your method try something like this:

```
@POST
@Path("/")
@Consumes("application/x-www-url-formencoded")
@Produces("application/json")
public String processImmediately(@FormParam("JSON") String json) {
    System.out.printf("Incoming JSON, decoded: %s\n", json);
    // ....
}
```

---

*** EDIT ***

You choose your method argument binding based on the expected content type. So for example if your Content-Type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (Form Data), then you would bind a @FormParam. Alternatively, for Content-Type `application/json` you can simply consume the request body as a String.

```
@POST
@Path("/")
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
public String processImmediately(String json) {
    System.out.printf("Incoming JSON, decoded: %s\n", json);
    // ....
}
```

If you find that you have URL encoded data when using the second method, then your client is passing its data to the server incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks, that looks nice, but unfortunately my json parameter is always null.
The only data my post request contains is an Accept: json/application header and a body with JSON={ "test":"test"}, is this maybe too less? When I remove the annotation, the whole query string is delivered again. So the annotation makes some trouble.

Comment: Well, you have to bind your method parameter according to the expected incoming content type. See edits to my answer above for more detail.